# Unsigned vs Signed Integer

Tags: c

What's wrong with this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int  i;
    for(i=100;i>=0;i--)
    {
        printf("%u ",i);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't work but if i use `for(i=100;i>0;i--)` then it works! 
or another way is to use integer instead of using unsigned integer.

Comment: unsigned is always >=0, so it loops forever.

Comment: when i is 0, print statement is executed, then i is decremented which then turns i into its max value, it's always greater than or equal to 0

Comment: You could replace `i>=0` with `i<101`, but would be cleaner to just use signed integer.

Answer (score 1):

Since variable `i` is declared as `unsigned int`, this condition `i>=0` never fails, hence results in infinite loop rotation.

```
unsigned int  i;
for(i=100;i>=0;i--) { /* i will never become negative */
    printf("%u \n",i);
}
```

Note that `UINT_MAX` is `4294967295` [see this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)  i.e it ranges from `0 to 4294967295` so when `i=0` it prints & gets decremented, next it won't be `-1`, it will be `4294967295`, hence above `for` loop results in infinite loop.

*another way is to use integer instead of using unsigned integer ?* you can do the same using `unsigned integer` also by replacing the condition part as `i>0` so that when `i=0` it fails & comes out of loop.

Answer (score 1):

An `unsigned int` can never be negative, so `i >= 0` holds **true** all the time. So, it is effectively an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong with this code?

`i>=0` is always true as `i` is `unsigned`.  Then `for(i=100;i>=0;i--)` loops forever.

---

To continue using `unsigned i`:

Since the coding goal always wants to enter the loop at least once, instead of testing the loop condition in the begining, test at the end.

```
//for(i=100;i>=0;i--) {
//    printf("%u ",i);
//}

i = 100; // or any unsigned constant.
do {
    printf("%u ",i);
} while (i-- > 0);
```

---

> another way is to use integer (`int`) instead of using unsigned integer (`unsigned`).(?)

Use `int`.  Of course this will not work if `i` needs to start at values greater than `INT_MAX`.  If such large values are needed, consider a wider signed type like `long long`.

```
int i; 
for(i=100;i>=0;i--) {
    printf("%u ",i);
}
```